# Time complexity dependent on magnitude of input

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I'm trying to analyze an algorithm that looks like this:

```
def foo(L):
    for n in L:
        for x in range(n):
            ...
```

What would be its time complexity? First I thought $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of elements in $L$, but that seems a little optimistic given that numbers can become very large. Then I thought $O(n^2)$ but that seem quite arbitrary too. $O(nm)$ where $m$ is the maximum value in $L$ perhaps?

Comment: Time complexity on magnitude of input? Can you define it more?

Comment: Yes, $O(nm)$, assuming the time complexity of the operations represented by "..." on the last line of the code is $O(1)$

Comment: Depends on $L$ and what's in the loop, obviously! (And what `range` means.)

Comment: I think our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) is enough to answer your question, or at least to guide you towards asking a more informed question (right now, you're attempting to pattern-match, not analyzing). (The second answer is probably more helpful here.) You can also check out questions tagged [tag:runtime-analysis+loops].

Comment: Relevant for identifying the worst case: is `L` a list or set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result of seems correct, assuming none of the omitted operations modify the values of the variables `n`, `L` or `x`.

For a fixed value $k$ of `n`, the inner loop (`for x in range(n):`) loops over the set (or list; it is irrelevant for the analysis) $\{ 0, \dots, k - 1\}$, which contains $k$ elements. The outer loop (`for n in L:`) simply loops over each element of $L$ for a total of $|L|$ iterations, $|L|$ being the length of $L$. Thus, assuming the omitted operations are executed in $O(1)$ time, we obtain a time complexity of $O(m|L|)$ (as you propounded), where $m$ is the maximum value in $L$.

Incidentally, if you know the average value for the elements of $L$ you could also use the above reasoning to derive the average time complexity as well. (Just plug in the average value for $k$.)

---

As pointed out by @Raphael in the comments, of course, there is plenty of room for improvements if more assumptions are made about the contents of $L$.

Comment: Using $n$ with another meaning as in the algorithm is a bad idea.

Comment: That's a very rough upper bound on the number of iterations of the inner loop. In fact, it may be off by a factor of $n$!